# java.lang.IllegalStateException:Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2

Tags: android, gson

Hi I am very new for android and in my app I am parsing Json obejct using Gson and I am displaying result in listView for this I used below code but I am getting exception like

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2
```

please help me some one

### json response:-

```
 {
    "Header": {
        "CutQuantity": 0,
        "ETAQuantity": 0,
        "IDRPrice": 229000,
        "MasterId": 65639,
        "Name": "VENICE SATIN DBY 21491 COL 25894",
        "POQuantity": 0,
        "ProductCode": "GG01054-14B",
        "QtyOnHand": 332.1,
        "ReservedQuantity": "332.1",
        "SellingPrice": 229000,
        "TotalAvlQuantity": 0,
        "USDPrice": 26
    },
    "Batches": [{
        "AvailableQty": 25.8,
        "BatchNo": "A001",
        "BinId": 128430,
        "BinName": "Dummy-700",
        "DeptId": 23,
        "DeptName": "G.700",
        "MaxBodyId": 128430,
        "ProductCode": "GG01054-14B",
        "ProductCodeBatch": "GG01054-14B-A001",
        "ProductId": 65639,
        "ProductName": "VENICE SATIN DBY 21491 COL 25894"
    }, {
        "AvailableQty": 40,
        "BatchNo": "A002",
        "BinId": 128433,
        "BinName": "Dummy-700",
        "DeptId": 23,
        "DeptName": "G.700",
        "MaxBodyId": 128433,
        "ProductCode": "GG01054-14B",
        "ProductCodeBatch": "GG01054-14B-A002",
        "ProductId": 65639,
        "ProductName": "VENICE SATIN DBY 21491 COL 25894"
    }]
}
```

### MainActivity:-

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);


        getAllTips(); //Getting friendArrayList data from Services
    }

       private void getAllTips() {

        try {

            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
            json.put("scancode", "GG01054-14B");

            if (CommonUtilities.isNetWorkStateAvailble(MainActivity.this)) {

                AsyncTaskClass task = new AsyncTaskClass(this, MainActivity.this,
                        json);
                task.execute(ServiceUrl.GET_STOCKDETAILS_ID_URL, "1",
                        "");
            } else {
                Log.d("==========>", "There is Network Error");
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void doPostExecute(StatusObject statusObject) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (statusObject != null) {

            if (statusObject.getResponseCode() == 401) {
                Log.d("==========>", "Session Has been Expired");

            } else if (statusObject.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                handleResponseData(statusObject.getMessage());
            } else {
                Log.d("==========>", "Server not responding. Please try again later.");
            }

        } else {
            Log.d("==========>", "Server not responding. Please try again later.");
        }
    }

    // handle the response
    private void handleResponseData(String result) {

        Log.d("Final is==========>", result);

        if (result != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);

                if (json.has("Header")) {

                    if (json.getString("Header").equalsIgnoreCase("null")
                            || json.getString("Header") == null) {

                        CommonUtilities
                                .showToastMessage(MainActivity.this,
                                        "Product Information unavailable with this Barcode");

                    } else {
                        System.out.println("your here");
                        handleTripsResponse(result);
                    }
                } else if (json.has("error")) {

                    if (json.has("message")) {

                        CommonUtilities.showToastMessage(MainActivity.this,
                                "" + json.getString("message"));
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

        } else {

            CommonUtilities.showToastMessage(MainActivity.this,
                    "Product Information unavailable with this Barcode");
        }
    }

        private void handleTripsResponse(String result) {

            try {
              Type type = new TypeToken<Response>() {
            }.getType();

            GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
            gsonBuilder.setDateFormat("M/d/yy hh:mm a");
            Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
            Response post = gson.fromJson(result,type);
            friendArrayList.add(post);
                int listSize = friendArrayList.size();

                if (friendArrayList.size() != 0) {
                     listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
                     adapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(MainActivity.this,
                             R.layout.list_item, friendArrayList);
                     listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                }else{
                    Log.d("=======>" ,"No data Available");
                }
            } catch (Throwable throwable) {

                System.out.println("Exception is " + throwable);
            }
    }
```

### CustomListViewAdapter:-

```
public class CustomListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Response> {

    LayoutInflater inflater;
    Context context;
    ArrayList<Response> coridersList = new ArrayList<Response>();

    public CustomListViewAdapter(Activity context, int resourceId,
                                 ArrayList<Response> items) {

        super(context,resourceId, items);

        this.context = context;
        inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        this.coridersList = items;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

        Response rowItem = getItem(position);

        View rowView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null, true);

        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        txtTitle.setText(rowItem.getHeader().getAlerts().getDeptName());

        TextView desc = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.desc);
        desc.setText(rowItem.getHeader().getAlerts().getProductCode());

       // ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
       // imageView.setImageResource(rowItem.getImageId());

        return rowView;
    }
}
```

### Response:-

```
public class Response {

    private Header header;

    public Header getHeader(){
        return header;
    }
    public void setHeader(Header header){
        this.header = header;
    }
}
```

### Header:-

```
public class Header {

    private TerritoryBean alerts;
    private String Name;
    private String ProductCode;
    private int MasterId;
    private int SellingPrice;
    private int IDRPrice;
    private int USDPrice;
    private int POQuantity;
    private int ReservedQuantity;
    private float ETAQuantity;
    private float CutQuantity;
    private float TotalAvlQuantity;
    private float QtyOnHand;

    public TerritoryBean getAlerts(){
        return alerts;
    }

    public void setAlerts(TerritoryBean alerts){
        this.alerts = alerts;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return Name;
    }

    public void setName(String Name){
        this.Name = Name;
    }

    public String getProductCode(){
        return ProductCode;
    }

    public void setProductCode(String ProductCode){
        this.ProductCode = ProductCode;
    }
}
```

### TerritoryBean:-

```
public class TerritoryBean {

    private int DeptId;
    private String DeptName;
    private int ProductId;
    private String ProductCode;
    private String ProductName;
    private String BatchNo;
    private String ProductCodeBatch;
    private int MaxBodyId;
    private float AvailableQty;
    private String BinId;
    private String BinName;

    public int getDeptId(){
        return DeptId;
    }

    public void setDeptId(int DeptId){
        this.DeptId = DeptId;
    }

    public String getDeptName(){
        return DeptName;
    }

    public void setDeptName(String DeptName){
        this.DeptName = DeptName;
    }

    public int getProductId(){
        return ProductId;
    }

    public void setProductId(int ProductId){
        this.ProductId = ProductId;
    }

    public String getProductCode(){
        return ProductCode;
    }

    public void setProductCode(String ProductCode){
        this.ProductCode = ProductCode;
    }

    public String getProductName(){
        return ProductName;
    }

    public void setProductName(String ProductName){
        this.ProductName = ProductName;
    }
}
```

Comment: same issue as this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20991386/expected-begin-array-but-was-begin-object-at-line-1-column-2

Comment: no i tried but that is not working for me

Comment: your json file is not in a correct format

Comment: hi i chnaged my code now i am getting exception like                                                  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.example.venkat.checkingservicesexample2.TerritoryBean com.example.venkat.checkingservicesexample2.Header.getAlerts()' on a null object reference

Comment: That data is not in JSON format.  Feed it to http://jsonlint.com/ to see what's wrong with it

Comment: u mean server not sending JSON format response?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does Gson fromJson throw a JsonSyntaxException: Expected some type but was some other type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33621808/why-does-gson-fromjson-throw-a-jsonsyntaxexception-expected-some-type-but-was-s)

Answer (score 0):

I think issue is in your json responce your json object responce should  like

```
 "Header":{
    CutQuantity = 0;
    ETAQuantity = 0;
    IDRPrice = 229000;
    MasterId = 65639;
    Name = "VENICE SATIN DBY 21491 COL 25894";
    POQuantity = 0;
    ProductCode = "GG01054-14B";
    QtyOnHand = "332.1";
    ReservedQuantity = "332.1";
    SellingPrice = 229000;
    TotalAvlQuantity = 0;
    USDPrice = 26;
}
```

and Json array like

```
 "Batches" : [
            {
        AvailableQty = "25.8";
        BatchNo = A001;
        BinId = 128430;
        BinName = "Dummy-700";
        DeptId = 23;
        DeptName = "G.700";
        MaxBodyId = 128430;
        ProductCode = "GG01054-14B";
        ProductCodeBatch = "GG01054-14B-A001";
        ProductId = 65639;
        ProductName = "VENICE SATIN DBY 21491 COL 25894";
    },
            {
        AvailableQty = 40;
        BatchNo = A002;
        BinId = 128433;
        BinName = "Dummy-700";
        DeptId = 23;
        DeptName = "G.700";
        MaxBodyId = 128433;
        ProductCode = "GG01054-14B";
        ProductCodeBatch = "GG01054-14B-A002";
        ProductId = 65639;
        ProductName = "VENICE SATIN DBY 21491 COL 25894";
    }
]
```

Comment: i chnaged my code now i am getting exception like                                                    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.example.venkat.checkingservicesexample2.TerritoryBean com.example.venkat.checkingservicesexample2.Header.getAlerts()' on a null object reference

Comment: can u please help me pitty?

Comment: In your customListViewAdapter getView() method you get null value of rowItem.getHeader()

Comment: yes your parsing is done now you get the response you just have to get proper data. print what exactly you will get in Response rowItem.

Comment: just have a look to this Example as you are a beginner in android  https://www.codeofaninja.com/2013/11/android-json-parsing-tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

Your biggest problem is that your JSON does not look right, please copy and paste it in the [JSON validator](http://jsonlint.com/) and make sure that it is correct.
Furthermore, please invest sometime to learn JSON - go through a [JSON tutorial here](http://www.w3schools.com/json/).

Also, please check the [accepted answer on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5490789/json-parsing-using-gson-for-java) - it looks like something you can really use, especially since you also have/expect array/list of values.

Your JSON should look like this:

```
{
    "Header": {
        "CutQuantity": 0,
        "ETAQuantity": 0,
        "IDRPrice": 229000,
        "MasterId": 65639,
        "Name": "VENICE SATIN DBY 21491 COL 25894",
        "POQuantity": 0,
        "ProductCode": "GG01054-14B",
        "QtyOnHand": 332.1,
        "ReservedQuantity": "332.1",
        "SellingPrice": 229000,
        "TotalAvlQuantity": 0,
        "USDPrice": 26
    },
    "Batches": [{
        "AvailableQty": 25.8,
        "BatchNo": "A001",
        "BinId": 128430,
        "BinName": "Dummy-700",
        "DeptId": 23,
        "DeptName": "G.700",
        "MaxBodyId": 128430,
        "ProductCode": "GG01054-14B",
        "ProductCodeBatch": "GG01054-14B-A001",
        "ProductId": 65639,
        "ProductName": "VENICE SATIN DBY 21491 COL 25894"
    }, {
        "AvailableQty": 40,
        "BatchNo": "A002",
        "BinId": 128433,
        "BinName": "Dummy-700",
        "DeptId": 23,
        "DeptName": "G.700",
        "MaxBodyId": 128433,
        "ProductCode": "GG01054-14B",
        "ProductCodeBatch": "GG01054-14B-A002",
        "ProductId": 65639,
        "ProductName": "VENICE SATIN DBY 21491 COL 25894"
    }]
}
```

Comment: hi @ishmaelMakitla ur free?

Comment: Yep, you need further help with this?

Comment: yes is ur free i will send my sample project please see where is mistack just 10mins enough because i am very beginner in android please help me

Comment: OK, let me know how I can help, I can then past the solution as an answer here to the community can also weigh in to suggest improvements, etc.

Comment: It would be more useful to show us where you are generating the response JSON, because the JSON that you generate is not correct - once this is corrected, then we can help you solve whatever errors you get. Specifically, show me where you call `handleTripsResponse(result)` - because from looking at the code, I assume the `result` is your JSON string (which is not properly formatted for a JSON).

Comment: hi if u agree i will send my sample app please see once

Comment: please help me u can easily find problem within minutes i hope

Comment: i am struggling with this problem since morning

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109688/discussion-between-ishmaelmakitla-and-krish).