# I'm getting error in retrofit(JSON) android

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I'm fetching data using retrofit. When I run my application, it goes under onFailure method. I don't know where am I getting wrong. If needed I can provide more code files of my project. Help will be appreciated. Since I'm new please help.
I have read other questions related to the same problem but none of them help.

Following is my code:

```
public class Description extends Fragment {
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private DescriptionAdapter adapter;
private List<DescriptionModel> DescriptList;

public Description() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_description, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    /*Create handle for the RetrofitInstance interface*/
    DescriptService service = DescriptClientInstance.getRetrofitInstance().create(DescriptService.class);
    Call<List<DescriptionModel>> call = service.getAllPhotos();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<DescriptionModel>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<DescriptionModel>> call, Response<List<DescriptionModel>> response) {
            DescriptList=response.body();
            generateDataList(DescriptList);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<DescriptionModel>> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Something went wrong...Please try later!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
private void generateDataList(List<DescriptionModel> photoList) {
    recyclerView = getView().findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    LinearLayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    adapter = new DescriptionAdapter(getContext(),photoList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Adapter:

```
public class DescriptionAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DescriptionAdapter.CustomViewHolder> {

private List<DescriptionModel> dataList;
private Context context;

public DescriptionAdapter(Context context,List<DescriptionModel> dataList){
    this.context = context;
    this.dataList = dataList;
}

class CustomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public final View mView;

    TextView txtTitle;
    TextView textView;

    CustomViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mView = itemView;

        txtTitle = mView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
    }
}

@Override
public CustomViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.descriptrow, parent, false);
    return new CustomViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(CustomViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.textView.setText(dataList.get(position).getId().toString());
    holder.txtTitle.setText(dataList.get(position).getDescription());



}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return (dataList==null)?0:dataList.size();
}
```

Under R.layout.fragment_description is my recycle view
Under description_row I'm having textview (actually im fetching text)

Comment: Use `Log.e("ERROR", t);` inside `onFailure()` method. Do not use simple Toast message. And [edit] the question, post error log here.

Comment: getting E/ERROR: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $.   E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Expected BEGIN\_ARRAY but was BEGIN\_OBJECT at line 1 column 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20991386/expected-begin-array-but-was-begin-object-at-line-1-column-2)

Comment: no didnt understood ...it is unrelatable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something is wrong with your `REST` operation. Don't look for the error in your `DescriptionAdapter`

`Response` you receive from network is not mapped properly. `JSON` data is not containing your object `DescriptionModel`. That's why you get the error. Make sure you are passing all the parameters for the `REST` call.

Or try to make the same call from some other platform like Postman. So you can read the `JSON` and see where the error lays. Good luck!