# Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path error with using retrofit application and spring boot

Tags: android, spring-boot, intellij-idea, retrofit2

I know this question has been asked before, but i seem to be struggling with fixing my error. I am hosting a local website from java using Spring Boot and now i have to implement an android application using retrofit. I am trying to get a simple task done of loading json objects from my website to a recycle view on android but i get the following errors:

```
2020-02-09 12:15:57.005 9204-9274/bootcamp.entelect.co.za.supermancomicstockapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
Process: bootcamp.entelect.co.za.supermancomicstockapp, PID: 9204
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:353)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:383)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:252)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:271)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.beginArray(JsonReader.java:350)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:80)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:61)
    at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:37)
    at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:25)
    at retrofit2.ServiceMethod.toResponse(ServiceMethod.java:117)
    at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.parseResponse(OkHttpCall.java:211)
    at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.execute(OkHttpCall.java:174)
    at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall.execute(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:89)
    at bootcamp.entelect.co.za.supermancomicstockapp.Presenter.BrowsePresenter$BrowseTaskFirst.doInBackground(BrowsePresenter.java:50)
    at bootcamp.entelect.co.za.supermancomicstockapp.Presenter.BrowsePresenter$BrowseTaskFirst.doInBackground(BrowsePresenter.java:36)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Here is my Browser interface:

```
    public interface IBrowse {
    void loadFirst(List<BrowseDTO> browseDTOList);
    void loadNext(List<BrowseDTO> browseDTOList);
}
```

my Browse activity:

```
    @Override
public void loadFirst(List<BrowseDTO> browseDTOList) {
    recycleViewAdapter.addAll(browseDTOList);
    if(currentPage <= TOTAL_PAGES) recycleViewAdapter.addLoadingFooter();
    else isLastPage = true;
}
```

my browse presenter:

```
 public static class BrowseTaskFirst extends AsyncTask<Integer,Void,List<BrowseDTO>>{
    IBrowse iBrowse;

    public BrowseTaskFirst(IBrowse iBrowse) {
        this.iBrowse = iBrowse;
    }
    @Override
    protected List<BrowseDTO> doInBackground(Integer... integers) {
        IBrowseService iBrowseService = APIClient.createService(IBrowseService.class, Token.getInstance());

        Call<List<BrowseDTO>> browseIssuesPage;
        browseIssuesPage = iBrowseService.getIssuesPaginated(integers[0]);
        try{

            return browseIssuesPage.execute().body();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<BrowseDTO> browseDTOS) {
        super.onPostExecute(browseDTOS);
        iBrowse.loadFirst(browseDTOS);
    }


}
```

my browse DTO:

```
public class BrowseDTO {

IssueDTO issuesDTO;
private List<StockDTO> stockDTOlist;

public IssueDTO getIssuesDTO() {
    return issuesDTO;
}

public List<StockDTO> getStockDTOlist() {
    return stockDTOlist;
}
```

}

and lastly my browse service/controller

```
public interface IBrowseService {




    @GET("/Browse/{pageNumber}")
    Call<List<BrowseDTO>>getIssuesPaginated(
            @Path("pageNumber") int pageNumber);



}
```

when running the application i see the application is talking to my spring boot application because it gets the data from the website but breaks when i try to view a list of all the items

**UPDATE**

Here is the JSON response:

```
    content: [
{
issueTitle: "52",
description: "When they arrive before the ruinous sweep, There shrieks are heard, there lamentations, moans, And blasphemies 'gainst the good Power in heaven.",
condition: "Average",
stockReferenceId: 49423,
availableQuantity: 0,
seriesNumber: 6,
price: 175.44,
publisher: "DC",
coverImage: "\Images\20.png"
},
{
issueTitle: "52",
description: "When they arrive before the ruinous sweep, There shrieks are heard, there lamentations, moans, And blasphemies 'gainst the good Power in heaven.",
condition: "Fine",
stockReferenceId: 24721,
availableQuantity: 1,
seriesNumber: 6,
price: 161.51,
publisher: "DC",
coverImage: "\Images\20.png"
},
{
issueTitle: "52",
description: "When they arrive before the ruinous sweep, There shrieks are heard, there lamentations, moans, And blasphemies 'gainst the good Power in heaven.",
condition: "Poor",
stockReferenceId: 74125,
availableQuantity: 0,
seriesNumber: 6,
price: 53.35,
publisher: "DC",
coverImage: "\Images\20.png"
},
{
issueTitle: "52",
description: "When they arrive before the ruinous sweep, There shrieks are heard, there lamentations, moans, And blasphemies 'gainst the good Power in heaven.",
condition: "Very Fine",
stockReferenceId: 19,
availableQuantity: 0,
seriesNumber: 6,
price: 43.06,
publisher: "DC",
coverImage: "\Images\20.png"
},
{
issueTitle: "52",
description: "Then I his alter'd hue perceiving, thus: "How may I speed, if thou yieldest to dread, Who still art wont to comfort me in doubt?"",
condition: "Average",
stockReferenceId: 49424,
availableQuantity: 0,
seriesNumber: 7,
price: 169.74,
publisher: "DC",
coverImage: "\Images\21.png"
},
{
issueTitle: "52",
description: "Then I his alter'd hue perceiving, thus: "How may I speed, if thou yieldest to dread, Who still art wont to comfort me in doubt?"",
condition: "Fine",
stockReferenceId: 24722,
availableQuantity: 0,
seriesNumber: 7,
price: 63.28,
publisher: "DC",
coverImage: "\Images\21.png"
},
```

Comment: post the JSON response as well.

Comment: @NaveenNiraula JSON response posted

Comment: Is your code on VCS ? Meanwhile please check : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20991386/expected-begin-array-but-was-begin-object-at-line-1-column-2

Comment: @NaveenNiraula my code is on VCS, and i have looked at that but i cant seem to figure it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The models you've posted do not conform to the json you've added in your question. When using retrofit without adding any kind of converters, the java models should match the json itself. Naming is also important.

To properly parse this object:

```
{
  issueTitle: "52",
  description: "When they arrive before the ruinous sweep, There shrieks are 
                heard, there lamentations, moans, And blasphemies 'gainst the 
                good Power in heaven.",
  condition: "Poor",
  stockReferenceId: 74125,
  availableQuantity: 0,
  seriesNumber: 6,
  price: 53.35,
  publisher: "DC",
  coverImage: "\Images\20.png"
}
```

You'd have to have a java object with the same kind of structure:

```
class Item {
  private String issueTitle;
  private String description;
  // and so on
}
```

The next step is to parse a list of these items. Since the root of your json seems to be another object, we need to create a java model that has the same structure as:

```
{
  content: [
      // ...
  ]
}
```

This can be achieved with the following model:

```
class BrowseDTO {
  private List<Item> content;
}
```

And now the retrofit call should return this class:

```
public interface IBrowseService {
  @GET("/Browse/{pageNumber}")
  Call<BrowseDTO>getIssuesPaginated(
        @Path("pageNumber") int pageNumber);
}
```

This now returns an object that matches the returned json.

---

The error you are getting right now says that you are telling retrofit that you expect an array - that's the `List<BrowseDTO>` - but instead you got an object - that's the root element in the json (`content`).

---

In this example, I've mentioned that the field names must match the ones from the json. Although this is not wrong, it's not necessarily true. Since you're using `Gson`, one of the easiest ways to change the name to something else is using the annotation [`@SerializedName`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6.2/com/google/gson/annotations/SerializedName.html) which will change the name in the json and lets you use whatever field name you want, i.e:

```
class BrowseDTO {
  @SerializedName("content")
  private List<Item> items;
}
```

Although this is not necessarily true for all applications, in Android we always add this annotation even if it has the same name as the field, because the release builds are often obfuscated and the field name will not match the field in the json for sure.