# Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $ on generate APK

Tags: gradle, gson

My project is run on AVD properly. but when i try to generate signed APK, gradle get this error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $
> Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more 
log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

I've used this command many times: `gson.fromJson`. but i can't find error source. (which file and which line).

**So how do I find the source of the error**

Comment: Did you get to the bottom of this?  I'm getting the same when trying to build..

Comment: I have the exact issue. It's come from nowhere

Comment: I also have this issue with the stable version of AS 4.0 after updating. Any solutions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Expected BEGIN\_ARRAY but was BEGIN\_OBJECT at line 1 column 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20991386/expected-begin-array-but-was-begin-object-at-line-1-column-2) (I could add tons of duplicates). And there is not even any code, which would produce the error log.

Comment: Update your gradle and android gradle plugin.

Answer (score 9):

I got this problem in Android Studio 4.0 when I did a Gradle sync. I fixed it by doing the following:

1. Open top-level `build.gradle` and change the gradle classpath to:

   ```
   classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0'
   ```
2. Open `gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties` and change the distribution URL to:

   ```
   distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-all.zip
   ```
3. Copy in `.idea\jarRepositories.xml` from a new project

No idea how or why, but it worked for me

Comment: Worked! Just accept a suggestion from Android Studio about "Update Gradle Plugin" and it will do everything automatically. This suggestion is showing after AS has been launched.

Comment: I didn't need step 3

Answer (score 4):

I got this error in Android Studio 4.0 when I did a Gradle sync after switching branches. I fixed it by doing this:

1. Build -> Clean Project
2. Sync Project with Gradle files

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I tried to build a "signed release APK". I was using Android Studio Beta 4.0.

To fix the problem, I've upgraded to Beta 4.0 v4 and it resolved the problem.

Answer (score -1):

i changed the place where my APKs generated inside and it's working fine now