# Can not build release apk after switchinf flutter from master to stable

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, flutter-dependencies

I can not build release apk, however i can build apk in debug mode. When i was in flutter channel master it was ok, but then, i switched to master and get this logs. Actually if i will switch back it will work fine, however some of my packages do not support features of master channel, so i must be on stable.

**Error log presented under:**

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:lintVitalRelease'.

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Failed to transform libs.jar to match attributes {artifactType=processed-jar, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for JetifyTransform: C:\educ-team\Educ-crossplatform\build\app\intermediates\flutter\debug\libs.jar.
> > Transform's input file does not exist: C:\educ-team\Educ-crossplatform\build\app\intermediates\flutter\debug\libs.jar. (See https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/158753935)

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with
  --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 54s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... Done                     115,3s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1

Comment: May be this help Before that try `Flutter Clean`,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62394034/flutter-can-not-build-android-apk

Answer (score 1):

try --dubug then --release and if this doesn't work try -- debug then --profile then --release