# fromJson throws exception JsonSyntaxException: IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $

Tags: java, json, udp, gson

I am using UDP connection to send a data from client to server, the data I am sending from client works like this, I have JSON data which is the main data I should get but for some other work I have to add some more info. So the main JSON data is inserted in another JSON data

main data:

```
{
    "id":1,
    "reporter":"asd",
    "topic":"asd",
    "description":"asdasdasd",
    "type":"TASK",
    "priority":"CRITICAL",
    "status":"NEW"
}
```

Second JSON data:

```
{
    "RequestType":"newTicket",
    "ClientID":"827_1592246581251",
    "TotalDataSize":116,
    "ThisChunkSize":116,
    "TotalChunk":1,
    "ChunkNo":1,
    "Data":"{\"id\":1,\"reporter\":\"asd\",\"topic\":\"asd\",\"description\":\"asdasdasd\",\"type\":\"TASK\",\"priority\":\"CRITICAL\",\"status\":\"NEW\"}"
}
```

So the second data is received in the server side and when I use fromJson function it throws exception:

```
JsonSyntaxException: IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $
```

Please let me know if you can come up with a solution.

Comment: Please provide more relevant information so that it would be possible to come up with a solution.
You convert the first JSON (main data) into String and add it as `Data` into the second JSON.  Does `Data` need to be an array or an object in the second JSON?  Or entire second JSON needs to be wrapped into JSON array like this: `[{"RequestType": "newTicket", ... etc.}]`?  Please provide the code how you build JSON.

Comment: You may need to review [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20991386/expected-begin-array-but-was-begin-object-at-line-1-column-2?rq=1) and check if you can fix your issue using the information it provides.

Comment: @AlexRudenko the first array needs to be an object. and second array is also an object. i just need to send this second array to the server and then convert it to an object. this convertion part is giving me the error