# Expected Begin Array but was Begin Object error in Retrofit

Tags: android, arrays, json, listview, retrofit

I am a newbie in retrofit libraries and facing this error while getting response,
Below is my JSON response and Java Code:

When i toast the response it gives me "Expected Begin Array but was Begin Object". I want to store my result in listview and i already have set my view and assigned values. but i am unable to get response from the API i have used.

I have copied my model classes from json2pojoschema website so , model classes should not be having any problem. if still needed, please let me know.

JSON:

```
{
    "destination_addresses": [
        "Unit no. 25-30, First Floor, Idea Cosmic Plaza, Block C 2, Palam Vihar, Gurugram, Haryana 122017, India",
        "863/2, Ganga Vihar, Block A, Sector 12, Gurugram, Haryana 122001, India",
        "Unnamed Road, Block C, South City I, Sector 41, Gurugram, Haryana 122003, India"
    ],
    "origin_addresses": [
        "964, Block C 2, Sector 3, Gurugram, Haryana 122017, India"
    ],
    "rows": [
        {
            "elements": [
                {
                    "distance": {
                        "text": "0.2 km",
                        "value": 229
                    },
                    "duration": {
                        "text": "1 min",
                        "value": 45
                    },
                    "status": "OK"
                },
                {
                    "distance": {
                        "text": "4.1 km",
                        "value": 4094
                    },
                    "duration": {
                        "text": "11 mins",
                        "value": 657
                    },
                    "status": "OK"
                },
                {
                    "distance": {
                        "text": "9.1 km",
                        "value": 9092
                    },
                    "duration": {
                        "text": "30 mins",
                        "value": 1791
                    },
                    "status": "OK"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "status": "OK"
}
```

APIClient For Retrofit:

```
private static final String BASE_URL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/";
    private static ApiClientMaps apiClient;
    private static Retrofit retrofit;

    private ApiClientMaps() {

        HttpLoggingInterceptor httpLoggingInterceptor= new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        httpLoggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(httpLoggingInterceptor).build();

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setLenient()
                .create();


        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .build();
    }

    public static synchronized ApiClientMaps getInstance(){
        if(apiClient == null){
            apiClient = new ApiClientMaps();
        }
    return apiClient;
    }

    public RetrofitMaps getApi(){
        return retrofit.create(RetrofitMaps.class);
    }
```

Activity Code:

```
public class LocationFragment extends Fragment {

    String vehicleType, damagetype, brandname, modelname, makeyear, locationstr;
    private ListView listViewPlaces;
    List<Example> results ;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_location, container, false);

        vehicleType = getArguments().getString("vehicletype");
        damagetype = getArguments().getString("damagetype");
        brandname = getArguments().getString("brandname");
        modelname = getArguments().getString("modelname");
        makeyear = getArguments().getString("makeyear");
        locationstr = getArguments().getString("locationstr");

        listViewPlaces = view.findViewById(R.id.listViewPlaces);

        Getlist();

        return view;
    }


    private void Getlist() {

        String units = "matric";
        String key = String.valueOf(R.string.google_maps_key);
        String destinations = "28.495430,77.020937";

        Call<List<Example>> call = ApiClientMaps.getInstance().getApi().getNearbyPlaces(units, String.valueOf(locationstr), destinations, key);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Example>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Example>> call, Response<List<Example>> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    assert response.body() != null;

                    results=response.body();

                    PlacesListAdapter placesListAdapter = new PlacesListAdapter(getContext(), results);
                    listViewPlaces.setAdapter(placesListAdapter);

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Example>> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Fail" + t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Interface:

```
public interface RetrofitMaps {


    @POST("api/distancematrix/json")
    Call<List<Example>> getNearbyPlaces(
            @Query("units") String units,
            @Query("origins") String origin,
            @Query("destinations") String destination,
            @Query("key") String key);

}
```

Main Model Class :

Example:

```
public class Example {

    @SerializedName("destination_addresses")
    @Expose
    private List<String> destinationAddresses = null;
    @SerializedName("origin_addresses")
    @Expose
    private List<String> originAddresses = null;
    @SerializedName("rows")
    @Expose
    private List<Row> rows = null;
    @SerializedName("status")
    @Expose
    private String status;

    public Example() {
    }

    public Example(List<String> destinationAddresses, List<String> originAddresses, List<Row> rows, String status) {
        super();
        this.destinationAddresses = destinationAddresses;
        this.originAddresses = originAddresses;
        this.rows = rows;
        this.status = status;
    }

    public List<String> getDestinationAddresses() {
        return destinationAddresses;
    }

    public void setDestinationAddresses(List<String> destinationAddresses) {
        this.destinationAddresses = destinationAddresses;
    }

    public List<String> getOriginAddresses() {
        return originAddresses;
    }

    public void setOriginAddresses(List<String> originAddresses) {
        this.originAddresses = originAddresses;
    }

    public List<Row> getRows() {
        return rows;
    }

    public void setRows(List<Row> rows) {
        this.rows = rows;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

}
```

Row.java :

```
public class Row {

    @SerializedName("elements")
    @Expose
    private List<Element> elements = null;
    
    public Row(List<Element> elements) {
        super();
        this.elements = elements;
    }

    public List<Element> getElements() {
        return elements;
    }

    public void setElements(List<Element> elements) {
        this.elements = elements;
    }

}
```

I want to fetch and store data in listview , Please Help

Comment: Please post Raw model class.

Comment: I have posted the row model class , Please Check

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Expected BEGIN\_ARRAY but was BEGIN\_OBJECT at line 1 column 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20991386/expected-begin-array-but-was-begin-object-at-line-1-column-2)

Comment: No , I am not able to understand that answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this

```
@POST("api/distancematrix/json")
Call<List<Example>> getNearbyPlaces(
        @Query("units") String units,
        @Query("origins") String origin,
        @Query("destinations") String destination,
        @Query("key") String key);
```

to

```
@POST("api/distancematrix/json")
Call<Example> getNearbyPlaces(
        @Query("units") String units,
        @Query("origins") String origin,
        @Query("destinations") String destination,
        @Query("key") String key);
```

And other changes related to this

As your response is JsonObject and not JsonArray

Comment: Actually i tried that earlier , the response was successful but i was unable to store that to listview.

Comment: That might would be an other issue. I have written the solution for the issue that You mentioned in the title of the question

Comment: How to store object in listview then can u please help me with that ?

Comment: If you are facing issue in showing the listview then change the question accordingly or post new question with the code related to that issue. So that someone can help you over that specific issue

Comment: Adapter expects list but response is returned as an object then , What can i do about that ?