# Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT kotlin

Tags: android, json, kotlin, retrofit

I have json like this. In my case when i click one product im giving that product to detailproduct. After that, i have recycler in my detail screen. I want to get recycler items by products array which id is equals clicked product id.

```
"id": 10,
  "published_at": "2021-05-07T14:54:35.496Z",
  "created_at": "2021-05-07T14:54:30.656Z",
  "updated_at": "2021-05-07T14:54:35.561Z",
  "products": []
```

I want to reach that products array. My api method is returning  Call<List. I tried like below code. But its getting Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $ exception. Should create extra data class for related products?

```
private fun fetchRelatedProduct() {
    api.relatedProducts(args.productId).enqueue(object  : Callback<List<Product>>{
        override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<Product>>, response: Response<List<Product>>) {
            when (response.code()) {
                200 -> onRelatedSuccess(response.body()!!)
                401 -> onRelatedFail()
                else -> onUnexpectedError()
            }
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<Product>>, t: Throwable) {
            Snackbar.make(
                binding.root, R.string.check_your_connection,
                Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG
            ).show()
            Log.i("sadd",t.toString())
        }

    })
           }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Expected BEGIN\_ARRAY but was BEGIN\_OBJECT at line 1 column 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20991386/expected-begin-array-but-was-begin-object-at-line-1-column-2)

Comment: Please provide your product model here. You are expecting an array, but your api is returning an object.

Comment: We need the `Product` class

Comment: No, we don't need ... we need json which you are getting ... (in fact we don't need it at all ... obviously is not array (which your retrofit client expects) but object - and that's exactly  what exception says - obvious soultion: let your model and api class are correct with what's api returning

Comment: @Selvin you are right `Callback<List<Product>>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are expecting a list of products but what you have is a wrapper that has a list of products inside:

```
data class WrapperProducts(
    val id: Long,
    ...
    val products: List<Product>
)
```

Then change your callback for that

```
api...enqueue(object  : Callback<WrapperProducts>{
```

The error is saying you are expecting an array but got an object, because the JSON is an Object, if it were an array it would be like this

```
[
    {...}, //product 1
    {...}, //and so on
]
```

If you notice the above example doesn't have the others attributes, like `id`

Comment: Yep ı was overthinking because of array. But its pretty easy. Thanks!