# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 13 path $.profile

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, mvvm, retrofit

This is how I wrote the code here. There are 13 data classes here. How do I handle these? And how do I fix this error?

my data class:
//

```
data class ProfileResponse(


 val call_permit: CallPermit,
    val educations: List<Education>,
    val languages: List<Language>,
    val profile: List<Profile>,
    val skills: List<Skill>,
    val trainings: List<Training>,
    val work_experience: List<WorkExperience>
)
```

my apiServiceClass:

```
     @GET("call/profile/{postNumber}")
        suspend fun getProfileShow(
            @Path("postNumber") number:String
        ):Response<ProfileResponse>
```

repository:

```
  suspend fun getProfileShow(number: String): Response<ProfileResponse> {
        return apiService.getProfileShow(number)
    }
```

viewmodel class:

```
 val 
response:MutableLiveData<Response<ProfileResponse>>=MutableLiveData()

    fun getProfileShow(number : String) =viewModelScope.launch{
       val res = repository.getProfileShow(number)
        response.value=res
    }
```

main class:

```
 viewModel.getProfileShow(ques.user_id)
        
 viewModel.response.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { response ->

    if(response.isSuccessful){
         binding.profileSurename.text=response.body()?.toString()
    }else {
         Toast.makeText(requireContext(), response.code(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
})
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Expected BEGIN\_ARRAY but was BEGIN\_OBJECT at line 1 column 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20991386/expected-begin-array-but-was-begin-object-at-line-1-column-2)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You get a list of objects from the response. But you only get objects. That's you get an error. You must declare in response profile in objects.

Comment: viewModel.response.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { response ->

            if(response.isSuccessful){
               
                val profileShows: List<Profile>? = response.body()?.profile

                val currentProfile = profileShows?.get(profileShows.size)
                binding.profileSurename.text= currentProfile?.username

            }else {
                
            }


        }) This is how I tried it. Can you please tell me how to do it ?? I don't understand. Please help.

Comment: Just use this  val profileShows: Profile? = response.body()?.profile